# Deciphering the meaning of "wire is lowered from axis" in this question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism

The question is as follows. *I am not looking for the answer* - I just can't figure out the terminology of part (c):

> A uniform magnetic field of 1.5 T exists in a cylindrical region of radius 10.0 cm, its direction parallel to the axis along east to west. A wire carrying a current of 7.0 A in the north to south direction passes through this region. What is the magnitude and direction of the force on the wire if,
>
> (a) the wire intersects the axis,
>
> (b) the wire is turned from N-S to northeast-northwest direction,
>
> **(c) the wire in the N-S direction is lowered from the axis by a distance of 6.0 cm?**

I don't know what "lowering from the axis" means, and I can't figure it out. Referring to [this page,](http://www.saralstudy.com/study-eschool-ncertsolution/physics/moving-charges-and-magnetism/2305-a-uniform-magnetic-field-of-1-5-t-exists-in-a-cyli) I found this diagram:

[image: Diagram for Question]

I hope I'm not being much of a lost cause. I get that the wire is passing through the cylinder perpendicular to its axis, but what does "lowering from the axis" mean? What is the diagram trying to signify?

---

*This question is originally from NCERT Physics Grade 12 (Part 1). This textbook is part of my curriculum.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set a cartesian coordinate system at $O$. Set $X$ axis from east to west. Set $Y$ axis from south to north. $Z$ axis is now *up-down*. Move $6cm$ along this axis (either up or down will do). As you can see in your link, only $16cm$ of the wire will now intersect the circular cross section.

Comment: I can't pin point exactly what clicked in my head, but this answer explained it! Thanks!

 For anyone who sees this, the lower diagrams are looking at the pipe from one of it's ends. The Axis (dotted line) is where the original wire was, and 2x is where the new wire is.

Answer (score 0):

The cardinal directions span a horizontal plane. You can illustrate the meaning with your hand: you can move it N-S, E-W, and you can lower or raise it.

The diagram is a bit misleading. It is "right" if you have it laying on a table as a printout. The "lowering" happens perpendicular to the paper or into the screen.

This is in accordance with the lower part of the sketch:

- The magnetic field (W-E) is in the direction "into" the sketch.
- The wire  (N-S) runs from left to right.
- The wire is lowered by 6 cm.